# replace NaNs with 0 for df columns where column name contains specific string (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as a result of a pivot which has several thousand columns (representing time-boxed attributes). Below is a much shortened version for resemblance.

```
d = {'incount - 14:00': [1,'NaN', 1,1,'NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN',1],
     'incount - 15:00': [2,1,2,'NaN','NaN','NaN',1,4,'NaN'],
     'outcount - 14:00':[2,'NaN',1,1,1,1,2,2,1]
'outcount - 15:00':[2,2,1,1,'NaN',2,'NaN',1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to replace the NaNs in columns that contain "incount" with 0 (leaving other columns untouched). I have tried the following but predictably it does not recognise the column name.

```
df['incount'] = df_all['incount'].fillna(0)
```

I need the ability to search the column names and only impact those containing a defined string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
m = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('incount')]
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].fillna(0)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
loop_cols = list(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('incount',na=False)]) #get columns containing incount as a list

#or
#loop_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'incount' in col]
print(loop_cols)
'''
['incount - 14:00', 'incount - 15:00']
'''
for i in loop_cols:
    df[i]=df[i].fillna(0)
```

Comment: I have applied to my real df and get the following error:
ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Error originates from the loop_cols line from what I can tell

Comment: Okey, I edited the answer. Can you check it ?

Comment: Thanks. It now runs without error, although my df still has NaNs remaining

Comment: Using the variable explorer in colab I ca see loop_cols dosnt contain any columns. The actual column name is "(in_flow_count, 2021-05-01 00:00:00)"...I assume this str.contains would still find "in_flow_count" from this?

Comment: Please use `print(df.columns)` and paste output to the question.